# Java ignores return statement

Tags: java, return

Every time I run this code (of course not all of it) Java gets to the println-part but doesn't return true but false. So it definitely finds the right element in the array but doesn't return where it should. I hope someone can halp me...

```
Token[] ps = new Token[lengthOfArray];

//main function and function call etc

public boolean find(Token token, int index) {
    if (index < ps.length) {
        if (ps[index] == token) {
             System.out.println("Searching at " + index);
             return true;
        } else {
            find(token, index++);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `return find(token, index++);` instead of just `find(token, index++);` ?

Comment: @Berger sadly it does 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your method `find` recursively. This way an inner call of find may return true but the outer find would return false.

You probably should change the recursive call of `find(token, index++)` to

```
return find(token, index++);
```